# A word that means "of or related to the bathroom"?

Tags: single-word-requests

Question is mainly in the title - any word that means "of or related to the bathroom/restroom/lavatory"... or even "toilet".  Thanks!

Comment: To ensure your question is not closed as off-topic, please be specific about the intended use of the word. YOU MUST INCLUDE A SAMPLE SENTENCE demonstrating how the word would be used. Please use the "phrase-requests" tag instead if you seek more than just a single word.

Comment: The problem is that there are many different connotations for "bathroom".  Are you talking about "elimination", washing up, plumbing fixtures, ceramic tile finishes, or what?

Comment: Perhaps you are after "toilet articles," which are the things you pack for a trip that will be needed in the bathroom.  But if you are telling fart jokes, you are engaging in "bathroom humor."

Comment: A supermarket would label an aisle with things you keep in the bathroom as "personal care".  That would include medicines, tooth brush, shampoo etc (not all people keep medicine in the bathroom of course, but I'd say the majority does)

Answer (score 2):

I believe the word you are looking for is *lavatorial*.

> Lavatory:
>
> 1. A room equipped with washing and often toilet facilities; a bathroom.
>
> Lavatorial
>
> 1. relating to or resembling lavatories.
>
>    "the lavatorial utility that was a feature of subway design"
> 2. BRITISH (of conversation or humor)  characterized by undue reference to toilets and their use.

Comment: I would have said "toiletial".